# Can google console display too many installs?

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

I recently put an app on to the play store, it's very basic and was mainly for the use of myself and my friends, it got 3 downloads in about a month then 2 days ago it got 40 in one day and then yesterday 450 in one day. Not believing what it was showing i checked the play store and it showed 5-10 installs. I'm not really sure which one is right as when the console showed the increase in download, google play also showed a few more reviews at the same time.

Comment: The play store listing is updated only after 2-3 days, that's why the statistics are different there.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

Google updates the statistics on the application on a public page after some time.  Here you can see the statistics at the moment, find out how many people installed, deleted and use your application.

Comment: Good news then, thanks. Are there any good alternatives to google play console for checking these statistics?

Comment: only using another services.. release builds in Hockeyapp for example. But better publish to Google play)